# Cookies not working in Web View with React

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-hooks

I would like to show the popup only one time with React Hooks. Since Local Storage isn't working on Web View I switched to cookies.

- The code below works on the browser without any problem but not in web view.
- Since it's a web app I'm using React web, not React Native.
- I'm using `js-cookies` to handle the cookies

```
function useCookies(key: string, initialDefault: boolean) {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(() => {
    const cookieVal = Cookies.get(key);
    return cookieVal !== undefined ? JSON.parse(cookieVal) : initialDefault;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (Cookies.get(key) === undefined) {
      setVal(initialDefault);
    }
  }, [key, initialDefault]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Cookies.set(key, JSON.stringify(val), { expires: 60 });
  }, [val, key]);

  return [val, setVal];
}
```

Here is a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mayer-7nflm?file=/src/App.tsx

Any idea of how can make cookies work on Webview?

Answer (score 0):

like localstorage, cookie maybe not enabled in app webview , unless you confirm it .if not work in limited webview, maybe have a try to  fingerprintjs .

Comment: I figured out that the issue is that I  need to know when the user closes the webview, which Idk. Any idea?